# Javascript alarm doesn't play the sound file

Tags: javascript

I am working on localhost at the moment, my laptop. I am the only user.

I made an online exam for a friend. He asked if I could make a bell ring or a message sound 5 minutes before the end of the exam, so the students don’t wait too long before pressing “Send” or they won't be able to send their answers.

I have this javascript. Someone told me it works for him. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1qnLcaw4/):

```
<script>
const d = new Date();

// if later than h, play the sound. It's past 11am here now!
// set the minutes later if this works
var h = d.getHours();
console.log({h});
if (h > 7) {
    // I put a hidden input on the page, with the value of the sound file
    // <input type="hidden" id="musicloc" size="55" value="mp3/fullstop.mp3" /> 
    var sound = document.getElementById("musicloc").value;
    playSound(sound);
}

// this should make an audio element and then play the sound            
function playSound(soundFile) {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    // maybe here the problem? What is 'src'?
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', soundFile);
    audioElement.play();

</script>
```

But I get no sound.

In Firefox I did see this error  :

> Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is
>   activated by the user, or media is muted.
>   19BEsW13.html:259:18
>
> ```
> NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user
> ```
>
> denied permission.

I can't get Firefox to repeat this error message.

I can't open

> console.log({h}) ReferenceError: h is not defined

Is this a Firefox settings problem? Can I change this?

Or play the sound some other way?

Comment: Your jsfiddle works for me, but not on the initial run.  Only when I hit the run button.  That's because browsers won't play sounds unless you interact with the page (to avoid being annoying).  Try adding a button that plays a sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Pedroski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10470463/pedroski) pointed browser does not allow playing sound unless the user interacts with the page.

One way to fix this issue is to add a button which user needs to click to agree to ring reminder sound.

for example:

```js
// javascript
let startBtn = document.getElementById("start")
startBtn.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let count = document.getElementById("count")
    let interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        count.textContent = --count.textContent;
        if (count.textContent == 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            let bell = document.getElementById("bell")
            bell.play()
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<audio id="bell">
    <source
    src="http://filipcicspagerprogramming.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/5/4/10541783/05-dive-n.wav"
    />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<p id="count" style="font-size: large;">5</p>
<button id="start">Remind After 5 Secs</button>
```

Comment: Is there really no way to just run it? The point is, the students are concentrating on their exam, they may not pay attention to the time. In a presence exam, the invigilator would say, "5 minutes remaining!" I have loaded webpages where a video starts without my agreeing or clicking.

Comment: Thank you! Great! I tried your code, it plays! We will just inform the students to click this button, placed right after the part where they fill in their name and student number, before then begin the exam. Then I will set it to play after 55 minutes. Not tooooo sure how to do that yet, but I can solve it, I think! Thanks again!